# How does etherscan checks that the contract is ERC20 standard implementation?

Tags: erc-20, etherscan

Suppose I created any ERC20 contract, how does etherscan recognise that the deployed contract is an ERC20?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Etherscan can recognize that the deployed contract is an ERC20 or not. However, you can check whether your contract is ERC20 compliant (for mainnet and single file only) by using the verifier below.

https://erc20-verifier.openzeppelin.com/

Comment: I mean if I mint some ERC20s to my wallet then on etherscan it shows them in my Token balances. How does it do that?